# auto login script need to login with multiple accounts stored in a txt file

Tags: python, text, split

I am having some trouble reading from a text file and automatically writing that information to login to a website.

So far I have written some code that will read from my text file and write the first 2 lines into the website.

All my accounts and passwords are written in this format - `myusername:mypassword #id`, and would like to split `myusername:mypassword` and input into the corresponding areas without using the `#id`.

My problem is, my bot is reading and writing the first two lines of the text file, without splitting the username and password. I would like to just read the first line and split them and add the information to the website, and then continue to login, then logout and redo the process with the next username:password in the text file until they have all been used.

My code looks like this so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
import getpass

def loginBOT(usr, pas):
    br = webdriver.Firefox()
    br.get("https://web.facebook.com/")

    user = br.find_element_by_name("email")
    user.clear()
    user.send_keys(usr)

    passwd = br.find_element_by_name("pass")
    passwd.clear()
    passwd.send_keys(pas)

    btn = br.find_element_by_css_selector("#u_0_2")
    btn.click()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file = open("accounts.txt", 'r')
    info = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    loginBOT(info[0],info[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the format of your file:

```
myusername:mypassword #id
myusername:mypassword #id
myusername:mypassword #id
```

Then you could modify your code to this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("accounts.txt") as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            line = line.strip()
            print('line {:3d}: {}'.format(i, line))

            if len(line) > 0:
                # this will only run when the line is NOT empty

                data, _ = line.split('#')
                usr, pwd = data.split(':')
                usr = usr.strip()
                pwd = pwd.strip()

                print('line {:3d} usr: {}'.format(i, usr))
                print('line {:3d} pwd: {}'.format(i, pwd))

                loginBOT(usr, pwd)
```

Note: I use `.strip()` a lot to reduce the number of possible errors, specially with line endings, spaces or tabs read from the file. I like to be rather safe than sorry.

Comment: thankyou so much! that worked a treat! am I able to slow this down, as it is looping and loading a new web browser for each account. I would like to login on one brower, and then logout and reload webpage and login with next account

Comment: I am not familiar with `selenium`, so I don't know how to logout. But I guess you would need to add the logout call after the line `loginBOT(usr, pwd)` in the loop, so the user gets logged out before the next login is attempted.

Comment: If you need to slow it down (more time between each login), the simplest way would be to use `time.sleep()` after `loginBOT(usr, pwd)`; but maybe there are more elaborate/better ways

Comment: thankyou very much for the support friend! you have helped me out a lot! I will try those functions =)